# Rails partial is not reloading until I refresh entire page (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
<div class="row" style="margin: 0 auto; max-width: 1000px; display: block;">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 25px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="row">
      <%= @reviews.count %> Reviews
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-columns">
    <%= render(:partial => 'reviews') %>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="button">
  View More
<div>

<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 570px) {
  .col-md-4 {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
</style>

<script>
  $('.button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://58a109ea.ngrok.io/shop/1?product_id=1259405967417",
      data: {
        offset: 2
      },
      success: function (result) {
        $('.card-columns').html(`<%= render partial: 'reviews' %>`);
      },
      error: function (result, err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

I have the above code in my show view. When the "View More" button is clicked on I need it to send a param to the controller and use that param inside of the active record call in order to change the limit of items being displayed.

Here's the controller that's receiving the param after the ajax call:

```
class ShopController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if request.env["HTTP_ORIGIN"]
      request_domain = request.env["HTTP_ORIGIN"]
      request_domain.slice!(0, 8)
      shopify_store_id = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: "#{request_domain}").id
      render json: shopify_store_id
    end
    if params[:offset] != '' && params[:offset] != nil
      session[:offset] = params[:offset]
    end
    @reviews = Review.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).limit(session[:offset])
  end
end
```

It I use puts statements I can see that the param is getting passed in and everything but for some reason nothing changes in the view until I refresh the page. Does anybody have any ideas as to what I can try?

Comment: `<%= render partial: 'reviews' %>` this cannot be processed by your browser .. you'll have to send stringified html as the response of your AJAX call from your controller

Comment: @sa77 Thank you for the response. How so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= render partial: 'reviews' %>` ERB templates are only processed at the server, your browser does not recognize ERB tags.
One way to do this is by stringifying you HTML response with `render_to_string` on your action to send it back to you AJAX call as JSON response

You can do something like this on your controller

```
def show
  @product = Product.find_by_product_id(params[:product_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @product.reviews
      tmp_response = { :reviews => render_to_string('shops/_reviews', :layout => false, :locals => { :product => @product }) }
      format.json{ render :json => tmp_response }
    else
      tmp_response = { :reviews => "<div>Nothing found!</div>" }
      format.json{ render :json => tmp_response }
    end
  end
end
```

Then on your AJAX call, make your AJAX request for `dataType: 'JSON'` and parse the string response to html and render it on your DOM.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',      
    url: "https://58a109ea.ngrok.io/shop/1?product_id=1259405967417",
    data: {
      offset: 2
    },
    success: function (result) {
      _html = $.parseHTML(result['reviews']);
      $('#reviews').html(_html);       
    },
    error: function (result, err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I get **Missing template shop/reviews** error since I'm using a partial (_reviews) not a template

Comment: that's for partial .. updated the answer .. just do `'shops/_reviews` if your partial is at `app/views/shops/_reviews.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Add `respond_to :html, :js` on the line under the class definition of your `ShopController`

Comment: def show
    respond_to :html, :js
    .....
end
Added it right there but didn't change anything

Comment: You also need to render the partial on the server side, move the `render_partial` to a `js.erb` file and render that from the controller

Comment: Can you explain some more?